# Visualizing IO other then seekwatcher

Tags: io, video, graph

**Is there any other programs that can generate visuals/graphs/diagrams (movie and pictures) to visualize IO across a full device other then seekwatcher?**

**NOTE**: *seekwatcher generates visuals(pic/movie) from output traces generated by blktrace. it uses blkparse to make sense of it all and generate human readable output it can parse for times,read/writes, and locations on disk and to generate the visuals*

I made a cool article about blktrace and blkparse and seekwatcher (because it was annoying trying to figure out how to install it perfectly - got many errors that I had to sift out, so this might help some people out):

http://www.kossboss.com/linux---blktrace-blkparse-seekwatcher---how-to-run-and-install---and-example-script-to-run-all-nicely

After working with it I realized I wanted something more.

I saw one cool tool but I dont think its available to the public(I hope it is):

Does anyone know where to get this tool (the one IBM used in their research?) I emailed their team for source code or access to the app (just emailed them 5 minutes ago so still waiting on that reply - if it will ever come...)

Comment: I think this is *roll your own* territory...